# How to get rid of unwanted Html and Css tags in Csv file?

Tags: php, csv

I have written a code that outputs all the table data onto the csv file. But in the output files the headings of table are displayed and the rest are html and css tags which I don't want in that output. The code which I have written is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                             "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<?php

//Connecting to database
include 'dbconn.php';
// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output=fopen('php://output', 'w');
$fileName = 'out.csv';
// $output = fopen('demosaved.csv', 'w');
ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="' . $fileName . '"');

// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('id','first_name', 'last_name','cell_phone','email','insurance_carrier','date_created','date_last_modified','call_resolution','date_of_birth','address','city','state','zip','pain','scar','ed','herpers','shingles','metabolic','source_id'));


// fetch the data
// $rows=mysqli_query($connect,'SELECT id,first_name,last_name,cell_phone,date_created,date_modified,best_time_contact from      newform');
  $rows = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT f.id,f.first_name,f.last_name,f.cell_phone,f.email,f.insurance_carrier,m.date_created,m.date_modified,m.call_resolution,m.d_o_b,m.address,m.city,m.state,m.zip,m.pain,m.scar,m.ed,m.herpers,m.shingles,m.metabolic, l.name FROM `newform` as f 
 left join medication as m on f.id = m.user_id
 left join livingdata as l on f.reference_id = l.id");

//die(print_r($rows));
// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) 
{
  fputcsv($output,$row);      
}
fclose($output);
//exit()
?>
<body>
<p>New Php </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: I have edited the post check now